# How remove packages

Tags: debian

Trying to update but it mentions software I I'm not even aware is installed. Afaik neither skype nor flux seems to be installed. How can I remove them completely?

```
jonathan@jonathan-laptop:~$ sudo apt-get update
Hit:1 deb.debian.org/debian buster InRelease                            
Hit:2 deb.debian.org/debian-security buster/updates InRelease           
Get:3 ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu eoan InRelease [15.4 kB]
Hit:4 deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates InRelease                    
Err:3 ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu eoan InRelease 
  The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4CDB129629A4B41A
Get:5 repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease [4,502 B]          
Err:5 repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease          
  The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
Hit:6 repo.steampowered.com/steam stable InRelease
Reading package lists... Done
W: GPG error: ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu eoan InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY 4CDB129629A4B41A
E: The repository 'ppa.launchpad.net/nathan-renniewaldock/flux/ubuntu eoan InRelease' is not signed.
N: Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: An error occurred during the signature verification. The repository is not updated and the previous index files will be used. GPG error: repo.skype.com/deb stable InRelease: The following signatures were invalid: EXPKEYSIG 1F3045A5DF7587C3 Skype Linux Client Repository <se-um@microsoft.com>
```

Comment: That the software isn't installed is immaterial to the fact that at some point you added those 3rd party repositories and neither is expected to work on Debian. Just remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to install software from a Personal Package Archive
that somehow is not among the sources, or some of its properties has changed.

These commands should reestablish this PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nathan-renniewaldock/ppa
sudo apt-get update
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about PPA. (find my solution in my answer above/below)

Comment: How did you add this PPA in the past?

Comment: Long time ago, don't remember.

Comment: PPA is added manually not with `add-apt-repository`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to clean up your sources repositories (In your case the third party repositories has been added manually):

```
sudo rm /etc/apt/sources.list.d/*
```

Keeping only the officials debian repositories in `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list
deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian-security/ buster/updates main

deb http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
deb-src http://deb.debian.org/debian buster-updates main
EOF
```

then :

```
sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade
```